# Link vignette to package

Tags: r, r-markdown, vignette

I created a package with rStudio not with devtools. Now i want to create a vignette and link it to the package so that i can search for the package in the library and should find a link for the vignette under the description file . 
I created a rmarkdown document in the same project as the package. I have the following settings but i dont get the link in the package for the vignette.
Which setting should i include to produce the vignette?

```
---
title: "Das Paket PoissonRegression"
author:
- name
abstract: 
         \noindent
          some text

fontsize: 11
graphics: true
lof: true
documentclass: article
vignette: >
 % \VignetteIndexEntry{myVignette}
 % \VignetteEngine{knitr::knitr}
 \usepackage[]{graphicx}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    toc: true
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    toc_depth: 2
    number_sections: true
    keep_tex: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to enter the following in your DESCRIPTION file:

```
VignetteBuilder: knitr
Suggests:
    knitr,rmarkdown
```

Also, I am not sure whether this matters, but I use

```
%\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
```

Finally, the vignette file should be in the directory "vignettes" in your package directory. So if your package directory is "PoissonRegression/", then there should be a directory "PoissonRegression/vignettes/" where your vignette resides.